Pullback of a section though a point vs. value of the section at that point
Let $X$ be a projective, integral variety over a field $k$, and let $L$ be a line bundle (i.e. invertible sheaf) on $X$. Now take a local section $s\in L(U)$ and a point $x\in X$ and look at the following constructions:

The value of $s$ at $x$, in symbols $s(x)$, is defined as the natural image of $s$ in the vector space $L_k\otimes_k k(x)$, where $L_k$ is the stalk of $L$ at the generic point and $k(x)$ is the residue field of $x$.
The point $x$ induces a $k$-morphism $f_x\colon \operatorname{Spec }k(x) \to X$, therefore the pullback ${f}^\ast_x s$ is an element of ${f}^\ast_x L=L_k\otimes_k k(x)$.


I suspect that $s(x)={f}^\ast_x s$. Is this claim true? How can I prove it?


These definitions look a little odd - $f^∗_xL$ under the standard definitions would be $L_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} k(x)$, which is always a 1-dimensional $k(x)$-vector space, while your $L_k\otimes_k k(x)$ is $k(X)\otimes_k k(x)$ which is rarely 1-dimensional as a $k(x)$-vector space (consider any variety of positive dimension).

Yes, you are right. Yours are the right definitions.

The element $s\in L(U)$ corresponds to a map $s\colon\mathcal{O}_U\to L$ of $\mathcal{O}_U$-modules. The element $f^*_xs$ corresponds to the the induced map $k(x)\to L_k\otimes_k k(x)$. We have a commutative diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{O}_X(U)@>{s}>> L(U)\\
@VVV @VVV\\
{k(x)}@>{f^*_xs}>>{L_k\otimes_k k(x)}
\end{CD}
$$
where the vertical maps are the natural maps coming from the respective colimit diagrams and the unit of the extension-restriction of scalars adjunctions. That this diagram commutes follows from the fact that $s$, as a map of sheaves, induces a morphism on the colimit diagrams defining the stalks and as such a map between the stalks, and from naturality of the aforementioned unit of the extension-restriction of scalars adjunction.
If we trace $1\in\mathcal{O}(U)$ through the diagram by going to the right and then down, we get the definition of $s(x)$ in your point 1. On the other hand, taking $1\in\mathcal{O}(U)$ first down and then to the right, the element in $L_k\otimes_k k(x)$ you get is essentially by definition the element $f_x^*s$ in your point 2. These therefore must be the same element.

Very clear explanation. Thanks a lot
